# Android Widget button

Tags: android, button, widget

with [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf) tutorial i have created a widget with buttons. In the code below when i click on ButtonP1 a toast msg is seen. I try do the same with ButtonP2 also, but only the one toast msg is seen that is set to the ButtonP1. How can i do that another toast msg appears when user clicks on ButtonP2?

```
    public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetmain);

         Intent active = new Intent(context, HelloWidget.class);
         active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
         active.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button P1");

         PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonP1, actionPendingIntent);

         Intent active2 = new Intent(context, HelloWidget.class);
         active2.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
         active2.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button P2");

         PendingIntent actionPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active2, 0);
         remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonP2, actionPendingIntent2);

         appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
   }

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) 
    {
        final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) 
        {
            this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) 
        {
            String msg = "null";
            try {
                msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "msg = null");
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "Out: " + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
}
```

I have tried this (ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER2 instead of ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)

```
Intent active2 = new Intent(context, HelloWidget.class);
     active2.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER2);
     active2.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button P2");

     PendingIntent actionPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active2, 0);
     remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ButtonP2, actionPendingIntent2);
```

with

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER2)) 
                {
                    String msg2 = "null";
                    try {
                        msg2 = intent.getStringExtra("msg2");
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", "msg = null");
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Out2: " + msg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //null
                }
```

after the same if line. In that case the msg2 variable is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use different request codes when retrieving the PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast. If not `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(..)` will return an existing one in your case, with the message from your first Intent.

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ONE = 10;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_TWO = 20;

....

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    ....
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE_ONE, active, 0);
    ....

    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE_TWO, active2, 0);
    ....
}
```